# Data is not loading to array in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJs. I'm trying learning it. I am facing a problem  but can't figured out what is the error.

I'm integrating AngularJs with SpringMVC. My problem is that data is comming from Spring controller but when i assign that data to array defined in angular controller. it do not copies to it.

This is my Angular controller

```
App.controller('productController',['$scope','productService', function($scope,productService){
var self=this;
var category={catId:null,catName:''};
self.categories=[];

self.categoriesForPrdouct= function(){
    productService.getCategories().then(
        function(commingData){
            self.categories=commingData;
            console.log(self.categories); //This line Prints Data 
        }, function (errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while fetching Categories');
        }
    );
};

 console.log(self.categories); // **This line do not prints the data.** 

self.categoriesForPrdouct();


self.reset = function(){
    category={catId:null,catName:''};
    $scope.myForm.$setPristine(); //reset Form
};

}]);
```

The first console prints the data but the second console do not.

and Second is i want to show the data in dropdown which i wrote it like this

```
<select id="itemCategory" ng-model="productCtrl.category.catName" ng-option="productCtrl.category.catName for category in categories">
</select>
```

Is this correct or wrong. i am confused in this one.

Comment: Are you using controllerAs syntax in your template?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle/plunker ?

Comment: Actually i can't make fiddle data is comming from server here

Comment: Can you show the data being returned from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are there no options?

See this :

```
<select id="itemCategory" ng-model="productCtrl.category.catName" ng-option="productCtrl.category.catName for category in categories">
</select>
```

Why did you add "productCtrl" ?

use this instead...

```
<select id="itemCategory" ng-model="productCtrl.category.catName" ng-option="category.catName for category in categories">
</select>
```

As to why the console.log didn't show, refer to other member's answers...

UPDATE: You are assuming that it is in the format category={catId:null, catName:''} while the value of categories is

```
["Apple","Black Berry","GFive","Samsung"]
```

You can either change it to {catId: null, catName:''} format or use it as is.

```
<select id="itemCategory" ng-model="productCtrl.category.catName" ng-option="category as category for category in categories">
    </select>
```

Comment: Still the Data is not loaded it just shows empty dropdown

Comment: better check the value of the data received from the server. The properties are case-sensitive

Comment: i have printed the categories. It is printed with me in this format. ["Apple","Black Berry","GFive","Samsung"].  So do i have to change category={catId:null, catName:''} to just var catName.

Answer (score 2):

Issue here is when you `console.log` outside the service call, it will print nothing because service call in Angular is `asynchronous.`

So whatver inside `then()` function will be called after few seconds and your `array object` will be populated. So nothing to worry!!

**In View**

You clearly mis-used `ng-options`. It's not `ng-option`

Comment: So why the data is then not loading into dropdown

Comment: Y u r using ng-options in such a complicated and wrong way? Just use ng-options = category in categories

Comment: I have ng-options still data do not comes in dropdown

Comment: use $scope.categories in controller. And also modify ng-options as I told above i.e. ng-options = category in categories. SHare the error on console if you find any!

Comment: What you have told i have done it. But error came which says                         Expected expression in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_' but got 'catName in categories'

Comment: ng-options="category.catName for category in categories" for this i'm getting undefined value in dropdown

Answer (score 2):

Or you can do one thing you can write {{categories}} to print data in html so as to you can have track of this variable in html page. and instate of angular js select you can modify the code where you apply ng-repeat

```
<select> <option ng-repeat="data in categories" value="data.catName"> {{data.catName}} </option> </select>
```

try this might be it will help

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the dropdown to have the categories right when the program starts, right? You go to your webapplication and the data is there, right?

Ok, well, there are a couple of things to notice here. Firstly this:

```
console.log(self.categories); // there is no data here yet 

self.categoriesForPrdouct(); //here you are filling self.categories
```

The function categoriesForPrdouct is supposed to fill the array self.categories. Even if categoriesForPrdouct would be a synchronous function, you cannot ask a variable for data but only fill the variable on the next line.

But then again, the categoriesForPrdouct is an asynchronous function. That means the callback function will get executed when your request is ready.

```
self.categoriesForPrdouct= function(){
    productService.getCategories().then(
        function(commingData){

           //so right here, this is the callback. You need to think of
           //think of this as code executed with a delay. This gets
           // executed when productService.getCategories() has finished 
           // doing what it is supposed to do. 

            self.categories=commingData;
            console.log(self.categories); //This line Prints Data 
        }, function (errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while fetching Categories');
        }
    );
};
```

Furthermore, If you want the data to be ready when your application starts, you should use the ng-init directive, like this:

```
<body ng-app="yourApp" ng-controller="productController as self" ng-init='self.categoriesForProduct()'>
```

Angular will run this right off the bat, filling up your self.categories variable.

I have a plunker with similar code [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NgMWgTfoSKimtpPlGm0j?p=info). Take a look at it, it might be helpful

Comment: Thank You now I understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
self.categoriesForProduct= function(){
    productService.getCategories().then(function(result){
            self.categories = result.data;
            console.log(self.categories); //This line Prints Data 
        }, function (errResponse) {
            console.error('Error while fetching Categories');
        }
    );
};
```